# Render page again to show icon and header

Tags: authentication, rendering, render, server-side-rendering, conditional-rendering

I want to make an app for my thesis diploma. It works really well with the backend and so all, but I have problems with the rendering on the client side. I have to refresh it manually to render the header. When you are not logged in with an account, the header will not appear. I have this login page:

```
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./login.scss";
import Button from "../../components/button/button";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ReactComponent as ViewModeIcon } from "../../assets/images/view_pass.svg";
import { ReactComponent as HideModeIcon } from "../../assets/images/hide_pass.svg";
import axios from "axios";

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let remember = false;
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    roles: "",
    showPassword: false,
  });

  const handleAdmin = () => {
    //isAdmin = true;
    values.roles = "admin";
    console.log(values.roles);
  };
  const handleUser = () => {
    //isAdmin = false;
    values.roles = "user";
    console.log(values.roles);
  };

  const handlePassVisibility = () => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      showPassword: !values.showPassword,
    });
  };

  const handleCheckBox = () => {
    remember = !remember;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin",
        {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        },
        {
          headers,
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        if (remember === true)
          localStorage.setItem("logInToken", res.data.accessToken);
        else sessionStorage.setItem("logInToken", res.data.accessToken);
        navigate("/dashboard");
        console.log("succes login");
        console.log(localStorage);
        console.log(sessionStorage);
        // console.log(res.data.accesstoken);
        //alex ajuta ma sa verific daca useru e user normal sau admin
        //din interfata si sa se potriveasca cu rolul contului pupic
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="left">
          <div className="side-nav">
            <NavLink to="#" onClick={handleUser}>
              <Button
                name="STANDARD USER"
                className={`third ${
                  values.roles === "user" ? "highlight" : ""
                }`}
              />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="#" onClick={handleAdmin}>
              <Button
                name="ADMINISTRATOR"
                className={`third ${
                  values.roles === "admin" ? "highlight" : ""
                }`}
              />
            </NavLink>
          </div>
          <div className="form-container">
            <form className="user-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              {/* <svg
                className="svg-arrow"
                width="66"
                height="18"
                viewBox="0 0 66 18"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <rect width="66" height="18" fill="#222222" />
                <path
                  fill="#222222"
                  stroke="#909090"
                  d="M 0 17.886 C 12.855 16.446 28.613 20.401 33 -0.025"
                />
                <path
                  fill="#222222"
                  stroke="#909090"
                  d="M 33 0 C 46.053 1.44 61.706 -2.515 66 16.911"
                  transform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 100 17.911)"
                />
              </svg> */}
              <span className="title">Log In</span>
              <br />
              <label className="label">
                <span className="email">Email</span>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setValues({ ...values, email: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
              </label>
              <label className="label">
                <span className="password">Password</span>
                <input
                  type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                  placeholder="Enter password"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setValues({ ...values, password: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
                <i
                  className="eyeIcon"
                  onClick={handlePassVisibility}
                  aria-hidden="true"
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <ViewModeIcon /> : <HideModeIcon />}
                </i>
              </label>
              <label className="check">
                <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleCheckBox} />
                Remember me
              </label>
              <br />
              <label className="submit">
                <button type="submit" className="primary" name="Log In">
                  Log In
                </button>
              </label>
              <br />
              <span className="member">
                Not A Member? Sign Up &nbsp;
                <span className="button">
                  <a className="here" href="/signup">
                    here
                  </a>
                </span>
              </span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <div className="text">Welcome! Let's sign in to your account.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

and this header:

```
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactComponent as LogoIcon } from "../../assets/images/logo.svg";
import "./header.scss";
import Button from "../button/button";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const Header = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  type JWTDeCode = {
    email: string;
    iat: number;
    exp: number;
  };
  const logOutFunction = () => {
    setAuth({ loggedIn: false });
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    navigate("/");
  };
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
    loggedIn: false,
  });
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: "",
  });
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState({
    nameU: "",
    surName: "",
  });

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState({
    initials: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem("logInToken");
    if (!token) token = localStorage.getItem("logInToken");

    if (token) {
      setAuth({ loggedIn: true });
      auth.loggedIn = true;
      const decoded: JWTDeCode = jwtDecode(token!);
      setUser({ email: decoded.email });
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/auth/users/${decoded.email}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setUserName({ nameU: res.data.name, surName: res.data.surname });
          const init = userName.nameU.charAt(0) + userName.surName.charAt(0);
          setAvatar({ initials: init });
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      auth.loggedIn = false;
      setAuth({ loggedIn: false });
    }
  }, [auth.loggedIn, user.email]);

  return (
    <div>
      {auth.loggedIn && (
        <nav>
          <div className="nav-bar">
            <LogoIcon className="icon" />
            {
              <div className="nav-bar2">
                <div className="navig">
                  <NavLink to="/dashboard">
                    <Button className="third" name="MAP" /> {/*DASHBOARD*/}
                  </NavLink>
                  <NavLink to="/meetings">
                    <Button className="third" name="YOUR SCHEDULE" />
                  </NavLink>
                  <NavLink to="/schedule">
                    <Button className="third" name="YOUR ACCOUNT" />
                  </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div className="right">
                  <div className="avatar">{avatar.initials}</div>
                  <div className="datas">
                    <div className="name">{userName.nameU}</div>
                    <div className="surname">{userName.surName}</div>
                    <div className="email">{user.email}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="button">
                    <Button
                      className="third"
                      name="Log Out"
                      onClick={logOutFunction}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        </nav>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

When I Login the header does not appear only after I refresh the page. And the icon, meaning the initials in the icon, appears only after I run the code with npm start, but if I refresh the page it does not appear. What am I doing wrong?